# Prove that $\mathcal{O}_{ i } = \{1, -1, i, -i \} \textbf{Note:} i = e^{ \frac{\pi}{2} i }$

Tags: group-theory

> Prove that $\mathcal{O}_{ i } = \{1, -1, i, -i \} \textbf{Note:} i = e^{ \frac{\pi}{2} i }$

Suppose $\beta = \dfrac{1}{4}$. 
Also I proved before this question that $n \cdot e^{2\pi i \theta} := e^{ 2\pi i (  \theta  + \beta n ) }$ is an action of $\Z$ on the set $\mathbb{T}$.

I know I can start by taking an element of $\mathcal{O}_{ i }$ and showing its an element in $\{1, -1, i, -i \}$. I am really unsure about the element in the orbit. Will it be just $n \cdot e^{2\pi i \theta}?$ Then if so, just by definition and using the provided info that would be $n \cdot e^{2\pi i \theta}= e^{\frac{\pi}{2} i (\frac{1}{4}n)}$? I feel a bit confused about the steps but I wanted to at least try something before asking for help.

Comment: What is $\mathcal O$?

Comment: It is the orbit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that by wierd $O_i$ you mean the orbit of $i$, this is my awnser:
Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.
By dividing by 4 we can express $n$ as $m+4k$, where $m,k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $0\leq m\leq 3$.
Then:
$$n\cdot i=n\cdot e^{\frac{\pi}{2}i}=n\cdot e^{2\pi i\frac{1}{4}}=e^{2\pi i(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}(m+4k))}=e^{2\pi i(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}m)}e^{2\pi i}=e^{2\pi i(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}m)}$$
So any element of $O_i$ is of the form $ie^{\frac{\pi}{2}im}$ for some $0\leq m \leq 3$, so any element is either $1,i,-1$ or $-i$.
Then we show that all of these four elements are indeed elements of $O_i$, by computing $0\cdot i$, $1\cdot i$, $2\cdot i$ and $3\cdot i$.
Then we can conclude that $O_i=\{1,i,-1,-i\}$.

Comment: Yes thank you, I actually starting working it out with my professor and came up with a similar answer, but you wrote it in a more compact way so thank you!